# Flashing Asuro Robot (Arexx) on OSX

Tags: c++, macos, flash, microcontroller, infrared

I'm coming across problems flashing my [asuro](http://www.arexx.com/arexx.php?cmd=goto&cparam=p_asuro) on osx lion.

After some fixes to the sources of the flashing program `con_flash`, as suggested in some forums, it compiled successfully.

The IR device is working, I can send/receive data to/from other notepads via `screen` command. I can even receive the native IR signals from asuro (such as `Starting XYZ-test...`).

The robot is definitely not broken, he can be flashed on windows. It's an osx issue, forum entries indicate that other users also had problems. But no solution is provided.

```
domain:asuro mike$ sudo con_flash /dev/tty.usbserial-AXWAUG8P Asuro\ 020.hex 
ASURO Flash Copyright (c)2003-2004 DLR RM
ASURO Flash comes with
ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY 
This program is free software
you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the
GNU General Public License
as published by
the Free Software Foundation
either version 2 of the License
or any later version


ASURO Flash Tool
Version 1.2
Author: Jan Grewe
(c)DLR 2003-20004
Linux Version

.
Open /dev/tty.usbserial-AXWAUG8P --> # always freezes here



^Cdomain:asuro mike$
```

**EDIT** 
The problem lies in opening the device via the `open` command. Didn't even work as I hard coded the device name into it!

```
bool CPosixSerial::Open(char* port)
{
char text[256];

#ifdef LINUX
/*
#elif defined(Q_OS_IRIX)  || defined(_OS_IRIX_)
    sprintf(portName,"/dev/ttyf%d",port+1);
#elif defined(Q_OS_HPUX) || defined(_OS_HPUX_)
    sprintf(portName,"/dev/tty1p%d",port);
#elif defined(Q_OS_SOLARIS) || defined(_OS_SOLARIS_)
    sprintf(portName,"/dev/ttyS%d",port);
#elif defined(Q_OS_ULTRIX) || defined(_OS_ULTRIX_)
    sprintf(portName,"/dev/tty%02d",port+1);
*/
#else
#error Wrong OS only LINUX implemented
#endif

    strcpy(m_portName,port);
    m_portHandle = open ((const char*)m_portName, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);

    if (m_portHandle == -1) {
        sprintf(text,"Could not open %s\nAlready in use ?!?!\n",m_portName);
        MyMessageBox(text);
        return false;
    }

    // configure port settings
    tcgetattr(m_portHandle, &CommConfig);

    // 2400 Baud
    cfsetspeed(&CommConfig, B2400);

    // Data Size 8-Bit / 1 Stop Bit / No Parity / No Flow Control / Zero TimeOut
    CommConfig.c_cflag = (CREAD | CLOCAL | CS8);
    CommConfig.c_lflag = 0;
    CommConfig.c_oflag = 0;
    CommConfig.c_iflag = 0;
    CommConfig.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
    CommConfig.c_cc[VTIME]= 0;

    cfsetispeed(&CommConfig, B2400); // fix for osx
    cfsetospeed(&CommConfig, B2400); // fix for osx

    // Set DTR & RTS
    ioctl(m_portHandle, TIOCMSET, TIOCM_DTR | TIOCM_RTS);

    if (tcsetattr(m_portHandle, TCSAFLUSH, &CommConfig)) {
        sprintf(text,"Can't write port settings on %s\n",m_portName);
        MyMessageBox(text);
        return false;
    }   

    return true;
}
```

I'll try to find out how `screen` on osx works, maybe I can adapt the funcionality.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the newest version of con_flash (http://www.arexx.com/downloads/asuro/asuro_flash_linux_mac_src.zip) and have the same problem.

I found the solution in the german Roboternetz forum:
http://www.roboternetz.de/community/threads/59640-osx-asuro-flash-tool?p=565801&viewfull=1#post565801

Instead of using /dev/tty.usbserial* you have to use /dev/cu.usbserial* which does not use the handshake apparently. I do not fully understand the difference yet.

Comment: Thx, but I can't test it anymore.